# Heroku free dyno working hours are not working properly

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have only one Django app with PostgreSQL running on heroku and I have `801.59 free dyno hours (80.16%) used this month`. Can anyone explain me how it is possible? `801.59:24=33,39` Today is the nineteenth of December, so where 14 days disappeared?

Comment: What's your billing cycle?

Comment: @Chris do you mean plan?

Comment: I mean your Heroku billing cycle may not start on the first of the month. "A month" for your usage may also start on a different day.

Comment: How can I check when cycle starts and ends?

Comment: I suggest contacting Heroku support. They should be able to tell you your billing cycle, but more importantly they'll be able to talk to you about your dyno hours more knowledgeably than we can.